# Dedicated Generator/current limiting/off-grid

Tags: relay, inverter, generator, current-limiting

I’m trying to design an off grid solution that would allow me to charge a Tesla (240v@48a) without having to buy a ton of batteries (since most car charging would be done at night)

I would like to buy a generator that is dedicated to this purpose. The problem is I need a way to turn it on when needed and off when charging is done.

My first thought was to buy an inverter that would be sleep until current is needed the have it turn on the generator when it wakes up. Problem is the inverters that I saw need a 50amp breaker limiting the incoming AC current. The line from the charger to the generator needs a 60a breaker.

My next thought was to use the inverter to start the gen then use a transfer to switch to a dedicated line between the charger and gen. Problem is that the line between the inverter and charger would need to be limited to the inverter rated wattage (say 1.5kW) and I’m not sure how that would be done.

Is there another way to monitor the charger outlet to see if there is need for power to control a relay that would control the generator?

Comment: Just so we're clear: Your plan is to run a CO2-spewing gas-fueled generator in order to charge your CO2-free enviro-car ... ? Do you realize that the inefficiencies in that system will end up using more gas to drive than if you'd just run a 'normal' gas-powered car ... ?

Comment: CO2 spewing? What about CO and N2O?

Comment: Isn't the Tesla smart enough to tell the generator when to shut down?

Comment: @brhans: virtue signalling works as long noone finds the corpses you hid somewhere.

Comment: If you don't want to feel stupid after your great achievement, make the charger solar powered / wind powered / water powered. Otherwise you will look like a fool in everybody's eyes, including your own when you finally realize what you've done.

Comment: Buy a hybrid: they come with a built in generator that can also move the car.

Comment: I creating biogas. I'll have excess gas that will break down into H2O and CO2 but will prevent a methane from going into the atmosphere